# Application of LC circuit(tank circuit)

Tags: oscillator

I have read that tank circuit is used for radio tuning. When we tune a radio we change the variable capacitor, hence the value of LC changes. This would result in a change in the resonance frequency. My question is how relevant is this technology to today's application of tank circuit.

Are they still used in modern radios, for example in my 2016 model car, or there is a new technology for radio tuning.

Comment: LC tanks: still in use, there is no other easy way to select a certain frequency band and suppress everything else. Variable capacitors: still in use but not mechanically variable capacitors, instead we use capacitors which change value by applying a varying DC voltage, a varactor. This can be a simple diode biased in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

In today's era of communication, all is going on digitally. Instead of using variable capacitor, people nowadays using ***Varactor Diode***. See below figure.

[image]

Applied Voltage across D1 will result into change in capacitance value.

> Modern electronic tuners also use varactor diodes as the actual tuning elements, but the voltages which change their capacitance are obtained from a digital to analog converter (DAC) driven by a microprocessor or phase locked loop (PLL) arrangement. This modern form allows for very precise tuning and locking-in on weak signals, as well as a numerical display of the tuned frequency.

Comment: *all is going on digitally* Yet you show a purely analog example ! The only "digital" in a PLL would be the frequency divider loop. The rest is all analog circuitry. I know, I design such PLLs. And in this example it's still an LC tank that does the frequency selection.

Comment: yes dear!, but tuning of capacitor is done with manually using knob in past and still somewhere, but all knows tuning circuit cant be digitally!! so my intention to say *all is going on digitally* is limited to tuning or changing capacitance of tune circuit

Answer (score 0):

Modern radios use either a varactor diode (VD) or a voltage controlled oscillator (VCO) or even a full phase-locked loop (PLL).

A VD is a PN diode with the property that it's junction capacitance changes significantly when biasing voltage is applied. This is effectively a voltage controlled variable capacitor. Since the radio is digital it can produce the biasing voltage using a DAC.

A VCO is a device that produces a oscillation with frequency dependant on the input voltage - again easier to control. However I'd say that the most flexible would be a PLL, since it can use frequency multiplication by a rational factor, and that factor can be directly written as digital registers.

In short - The times of turning a variable capacitor to tune the ratio are long gone.

Side note - There were also radios where you tune the LC circuit by mechanically moving the inductor core in and out to change the inductance.

Comment: And what determines the frequency of a VCO ? An LC tank ! And how does such a VCO change frequency ? By changing the capacitance in the tank by means of a varactor or maybe a switched capacitor bank.

Comment: I'd say more often it's an RC circuit than LC. Integrating coils in ICs is a pain, since the inductance is low, no core can be added and due to thin metal traces the resistance is high resulting in a poor quality factor. An equivalent of an inductor can be made using capacitors and an inverting amplifier. I'd still say that for a car radio you'd use a quartz crystal with a PLL to multiply/divide the frequency into the desired output. Of course, the VCO, phase detector and loop filter still remain analog RC circuits. It's the dividers which are digitally programmable.

Comment: For low frequencies ( < 1 GHz) you are right on chip inductors are not a good choice. But above 1 GHz many ICs use on chip inductors. There's a chip from Broadcom that has around 20 of them. I have designed many on-chip VCO and phase detectors, they are **not** RC based as the R gives you noise !